# How do you get the first and last day using Carbon and only year and month?

Tags: php, laravel

I only have 2 strings, year and month. And I need to get the first and last day using Carbon. For example, '2020' and '3' are provided. I would need to get 2 Carbon dates out of these (2020-3-1 and 2020-3-31). Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To achieve your goal use the following codes:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon; // imports the Carbon class
$year = 2020;
$month = 3;
$date_1 = Carbon::create($year, $month)->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'); //returns 2020-03-01
$date_2 = Carbon::create($year, $month)->lastOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'); //returns 2020-03-31
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it simply with carbon methods like `startOfMonth` and `endOfMonth` as below

```
$startOfMonth=\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2020-3')->startOfMonth()->format('Y-n-d');
$endOfMonth=\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2020-3')->endOfMonth()->format('Y-n-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [Carbon Documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation)

```
Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $tz);
```

> The only special case is for `create()` that has **minimum value as
>   default for missing argument** but default on current value when you
>   pass explicitly null.

So if you pass only `$year` and  `$month`  it will automatically considered first day and then you can `format()` function it to get the first day as day for e.g.

```
Carbon::create($year, $month)->format("Y-m-d")
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this method to get the 1st and last day of the month.

`t` represents the last day of the month.

```
$posts = Post::whereBetween('created_at', [
Carbon::createFromDate(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime(request('year') . '-' . request('month') . '-1'))),
Carbon::createFromDate(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime(request('year') . '-' . request('month') . '-t')))])
->get();

return $posts
```

**Edit:**
I use `+` on the `php` but it is `.` sorry.

or you can use this:

```
$this->client = $this->client->whereBetween('created_at', [
Carbon::createFromDate(date(request('year') . '-' . request('month') . '-01 00:00:00')),
Carbon::createFromDate(date(request('year') . '-' . request('month') . '-12 23:59:59'))])
->get();
```

**Edit:(Edit:)**

Base on your question you need to get the first and last day.
But in the real world the 1st day is given so you need only to get the last day.
It should be like this.

The first day should be given because we all know that it falls to 1.

```
$firstDayOfTheMonth = date(request('year') . '-' . request('month') . '-1 00:00:00');

$lastDayOfTheMonth = date(request('year') . '-' . request('month') . '-t 23:59:59');
```

Comment: im not sure why would you incorporate a where clause, the OP just said how to get the first day and last day from two strings (year and month), and you're using carbon already, no need for date and strtotime stuff

Comment: oohhh. I see sorry

Comment: just simply use `$date = Carbon::create($year, $month);`, its automatically understood it starts with the first day, and simply just use `->format` with `Y-m-d` and `Y-m-t`, thats it, the application is up to the OP

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I'm actually going to use this for query where clause.